# While True Algorithm iteration Python

Tags: python, while-loop, conditional-statements, cycle

I have this code:

```
split_at = q[:,3].searchsorted([1,random.randrange(LB,UB-I)])
D = numpy.split(q, split_at) 
T=D[1]
TF=D[2]
T2=copy(TF)
T2[:,3]=T2[:,3]+I
u=random.sample(T[:],1)
v=random.sample(T2[:],1)
u=array(u)
v=array(v)
d=v[0,0]-u[0,0]+T[-1,3]
```

I want that `if`d<=1000 :

```
x=numpy.where(v==T2)[0][0]
y=numpy.where(u==T)[0][0]
l=np.copy(T[y])
T[y],T2[x]=T2[x],T[y]
T2[x],l=l,T2[x]
E=np.copy(T)
E2=np.copy(T2)
E[:,3]=np.cumsum(E[:,0])
E2[:,3]=np.cumsum(E2[:,0])+I
f2=sum(E[:,1]*E[:,3])+sum(E2[:,1]*E2[:,3])
```

And than that `if d>1000` I want ot recalculate the first part of code and verify `if d<=1000` and this over and over again until the condition is met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about starting with:

```
d = 1000000
while d > 1000:
    split_at = q[:,3].searchsorted([1,random.randrange(LB,UB-I)])
    D = numpy.split(q, split_at) 
    T=D[1]
    TF=D[2]
    T2=copy(TF)
    T2[:,3]=T2[:,3]+I
    u=random.sample(T[:],1)
    v=random.sample(T2[:],1)
    u=array(u)
    v=array(v)
    d=v[0,0]-u[0,0]+T[-1,3]
x=numpy.where(v==T2)[0][0]
y=numpy.where(u==T)[0][0]
l=np.copy(T[y])
T[y],T2[x]=T2[x],T[y]
T2[x],l=l,T2[x]
E=np.copy(T)
E2=np.copy(T2)
E[:,3]=np.cumsum(E[:,0])
E2[:,3]=np.cumsum(E2[:,0])+I
f2=sum(E[:,1]*E[:,3])+sum(E2[:,1]*E2[:,3])
```

Comment: I don't know if If I can because d has to be a fixed value that i use in some other passages @sharcashmo

Comment: I don't understand why d = 1000000 and then d=v[0,0]-u[0,0]+T[-1,3]

Comment: Thank you It Works very well. I runned for several times and never occurred a d>1000. Ty

Comment: Do you think I can Iterate this process? if f2-f<0 My new T=E and my new E2=T2 and recalculate over and over again? How? @sharcashmo

Answer (score 0):

Why not arranging the code into functions like:

```
def func1(): # add your arguments to param list
   split_at = q[:,3].searchsorted([1,random.randrange(LB,UB-I)])
   # some code 
   d=v[0,0]-u[0,0]+T[-1,3]
   return d,T,T2

def func2(T,T2):
   x=numpy.where(v==T2)[0][0]
   # more code
```

and just do something like:

```
d = 10000
while  d > 1000:
   d,T,T2 = func1()
else:
   func2(T,T2)
```

Comment: I think this could work but after else I iterate untile the condition d<=1000?

Comment: I have this error: IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-e74acdb4c4c8> in <module>()
     66    pass
     67 else:
---> 68    func2()

<ipython-input-50-e74acdb4c4c8> in func2()
     52     return d
     53 def func2():
---> 54     x=numpy.where(v==T2)[0][0]
     55     y=numpy.where(u==T)[0][0]
     56     l=np.copy(T[y])

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0 @greole